# Compare data from Flutter app with the data in Firestore documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a quiz app using flutter and firebase. I used stream builders to display questions and options from Firestore. I now want to compare the option selected by the user with the correct answer present in the firestore documents. So I am trying to read and store the answers from firestore into a list and then compare it to the selected answer. I don't want to use a streambuilder or futurebuilder because I am not going to display the data. I am unable to find a way to do this. How do I approach this problem?

**My code:**

```
class _OptionsWidgetState extends State<OptionsWidget> {
int selectedIndex = -1;
bool isSelected = false;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return SizedBox(height: 15.sp);
  },
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.h, horizontal: 50.w),
  itemCount: 4,
  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        isSelected == false
            ? {
                setState(
                  () {
                    isSelected = true;
                    selectedIndex = index;
                  },
                ),

                //COMPARING THE CORRECT ANSWER(Index) WITH THE SELECTED INDEX. I AM USING A SAMPLE ANSWERS LIST . 
                //HERE I WANT TO USE THE LIST OF ANSWERS RETRIEVED FROM FIRESTORE.

                if (selectedIndex == answers[widget.questionNumber])
                  Provider.of<TotalScore>(context, listen: false)
                      .updateScore(10),
                print(Provider.of<TotalScore>(context, listen: false)
                    .totalScore),
              }
            : null;
      },
      child: Container(
        ...
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Options(
                    index: widget.questionNumber, optionindex: index)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }),
);
}
}

final List<int> answers = [2,3,1,2,3,1,4,1,5];
```

**My firestore database structure:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Below code to show how I am fetching the questions.

I am using PageView to display question widgets:

```
class _Quiz1State extends State<Quiz1> {
final PageController _pageController = PageController(
initialPage: 0,
);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: PageView(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _pageController,
      children: [
        QuestionWidget(
          currentQuestion: 1,
          pageController: _pageController,
          totalQuestions: 10,
          // question: 'Why is speed relative?',
          question: const Question(index: 0),
          index: 0,
        ),
        QuestionWidget(
          currentQuestion: 2,
          pageController: _pageController,
          totalQuestions: 10,
          // question: 'How is universe expanding?',
          question: const Question(index: 1),
          index: 1,
        ),

        .....

        CheckScoreWidget(pageController: _pageController),
        ResultsWidget(),
      ],
      ),
      }
```

Using stream builder to fetch questions:

```
class Question extends StatelessWidget {
const Question({
Key? key,
required this.index,
}) : super(key: key);
final int index;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quiz1').snapshots();
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _usersStream,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) 
{
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Text('Something went wrong');
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text(" "),
      );
    }
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>> data = snapshot.data!.docs;

    return Text(
      data[index]['title'],
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
        fontSize: 16.sp,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    );
   },
  );
 }
}
```

Question Widget:

```
class QuestionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
const QuestionWidget({
Key? key,
required this.currentQuestion,
required this.pageController,
required this.question,
required this.totalQuestions,
required this.index,
}) : super(key: key);

final int currentQuestion;
final PageController pageController;
final Widget question;
final int totalQuestions;
final int index;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  ....
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.h,
      ),
      OptionsWidget(questionNumber: index),
    ],
  ),
 );
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're already pulling down the answers with each question. What does your Question model class look like? You could add the answer value to that model class, then compare it to the option the user selected.

    `class QuestionModel { final int answer; final List<String> options; final String title; }`

Then in code you would just compare `selectedIndex == question.answer`

Comment: @Andrew But I need to fetch that answer value from firestore and store it in the variable 'answer' right? This is where I am facing problems. I looked and tried many solutions but the variable either returns null or instance of "some type". Can you answer with a simple sample code on how to fetch and store data in a variable?

Comment: Yes I can do that, but first can you edit your answer with an example of how you are fetching the questions in the first place? Then I can answer your problem more specifically. Feel free to obfuscate any details that are private like names of collections or keys or whatever

Comment: @Andrew updated my question. Feel free to ask anything else if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would create a new class called QuestionModel (or something similar) to hold the data for a single question:

```
class QuestionModel {
  final String title;
  final String answer;
  final List<String> options;

  QuestionModel({
    required this.title,
    required this.answer,
    required this.options,
  });
}
```

Then I would move your firebase logic up a level to the `Quiz1` class you have. This allows you to dynamically build the list of questions instead of having to manually do it. This also means you can probably straight up get rid of your `Question` stateless widget:

```
class _Quiz1State extends State<Quiz1> {
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> _quiz;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Move to initState
    _quiz = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quiz1').snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _quiz,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return PageView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: snapshot.data!.docs
                // Here we map every document from firebase into a QuestionModel
                // and pass the model class to the QuestionWidget
                // We no longer have to manually track the indices of the questions
                .map(
                  (question) => QuestionWidget(
                    question: QuestionModel(
                      title: question['title'],
                      answer: question['answer'],
                      options: question['options'],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'd like to point out that the `question[title]` and similar code will only work if the firebase data types match the QuestionModel types. If this were a production app, I would do some type checking to make sure everything is correct before I do anything with the data. Perhaps you could change the type of `answer` to a Number in firebase and then assign it to an int in `QuestionModel`. I'll leave that to you to decide. Anyway, now that we have our data in a `List<QuestionModel>` we can pass that into a `QuestionWidget`:

```
// This was modified to be very basic. Just pass the question in and display the fields
class QuestionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuestionWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.question,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final QuestionModel question;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          question.title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          question.answer.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,
          ),
        ),
        ...question.options.map((option) => Text(option)).toList(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The `map` function I keep using basically transforms a list of data into a corresponding list of widgets. It spits out an Iterable so we need to use `toList()`.

Here is a question for you: How do you think you could modify the data model to eliminate the `answer` field? Perhaps you could change `options` to take in a new AnswerModel class like so:

```
class AnswerModel {
  final String answer;
  final bool isCorrect;

  AnswerModel({
    required this.answer,
    required this.isCorrect,
  });
}
```

Now each individual answer "knows" if it's the right answer or not, and you don't have to manually compare different fields. I'll leave this up to you to decide if that's right for you. Also note that I removed a lot of your code that wasn't necessary to answering your question, so I'll also leave that up to you to fit back in.